# How to simplify event handling in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

This is probably a very simple question. How would you reasonably simplify this awesome code? I am going to add much more eventhandlers and list items, and I can not believe, it is the only "solution". I am new to javascript (but not in programming).

```
    function MouseOver(elem)
    {
    elem.style = "font-weight:800;";
    }

    function MouseOut(elem)
    {
    elem.style = "font-weight:100;";
    }
...
    <ul class="signs_UL" style="color:#039">
        <li class="signs_LI" onmouseover="MouseOver(this);" onmouseout="MouseOut(this);">G</li>
        <li class="signs_LI" onmouseover="MouseOver(this);" onmouseout="MouseOut(this);">D</li>
        <li class="signs_LI" onmouseover="MouseOver(this);" onmouseout="MouseOut(this);">DD</li>
        <li class="signs_LI" onmouseover="MouseOver(this);" onmouseout="MouseOut(this);">Dzw</li>
        <li class="signs_LI" onmouseover="MouseOver(this);" onmouseout="MouseOut(this);">Do</li>
        <li class="signs_LI" onmouseover="MouseOver(this);" onmouseout="MouseOut(this);">Gkomb</li>
        <li class="signs_LI" onmouseover="MouseOver(this);" onmouseout="MouseOut(this);">DGkomb</li>
        <li class="signs_LI" onmouseover="MouseOver(this);" onmouseout="MouseOut(this);">DGkonf</li>
        <li class="signs_LI" onmouseover="MouseOver(this);" onmouseout="MouseOut(this);">DGkont</li>    
    </ul>
```

thanx a lot

Comment: i know that with jQuery you can assign handler to all elements of class (signs_LI) with one line. but i don't know how :(

Comment: Do you mind using jQuery? or do you want to stick with classic JS?

Comment: this would be relatively easy to do with jQuery...

Comment: I downloaded jQuery today (couple hours ago), I do not mind to use it.... :-)

Comment: use css :hover. its much more ideal IMO.

Comment: I would stick with "bold" and "normal". 100 and 800 will come out that way anyway - and you may get unpleasantly surprised in some rouge UA.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If all you want to do is related to styling, you should use css instead of javascript:

```
ul.signs_UL li {
    font-weight: 100;
}

ul.signs_UL li:hover {
    font-weight: 800;
}
```

Will automatically change the font-weight on hovering over any list item in a signs_UL list.

Comment: eh, i see... nightmare... what would you do in my case? jquery?

Comment: @lyborko: I would drop support for IE6 ;) :D

Comment: @lyborko: If you need IE6 support, wrap the content of the `<li>` elements with an `<a>`, then place the `:hover` on that. `ul.signs_UL li a:hover` You'll also need to adjust the CSS of the `<a>` to expand it to the same size as the parent `<li>` so you get the effect when hovering any part of the `<li>`.

Comment: Also, be careful if you are using other classes inside that `ul`, Bart did not specify the class for the `li` to reduce redundancy, but you might have different types of `li`s listed.

Comment: Or don't support IE 6. Seriously. Even Microsoft wants it to die. http://www.ie6countdown.com/ <-- site made by Microsoft. I have a page I show for IE 6 users that explains the security risks of their browser, links to upgrade pages

Answer (score 3):

in jQuery you can do it with

```
$('li.signs_LI').mouseover(MouseOver).mouseout(MouseOut);
```

You can also do it with

```
$('li.signs_LI').hover(MouseOver, MouseOut);
```

but this would bind the events to `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` not to `mouseover` and `mouseout`.

I'm sure you know that you can do this with CSS with the pseudo class `:hover` to change the style on mouse hovering.

Comment: This would apply the mouseover/mouseout handler to all LI tags on the page, which is probably not what OP wants.

Comment: I didn't down-vote this because he endorsed CSS, but you shouldn't abuse jQuery by assigning event listeners to so many nodes (See @Felix King's answer).

Comment: me.  I don't think you can call it like that, you have to pass a parameter to the function.  In jQuery `this` isn't automatically supplied see my answer

Comment: @vol7ron: Actually, `this` in event handlers (in jQuery) always refers to the element the event is raised on (or the event handler is attached to). That is why you see `$(this)` so often in event handlers. Of course in order to make it work with the OPs code, `elem` must be renamed to `this`.

Answer (score 3):

As you assign the *same* event handlers to every `li` object, it would be much better to assign them to the parent `ul` element instead, making use of event bubbling. This is called **event delegation**:

```
function MouseOver(event) {
    event = event || window.event; // IE uses window.event
    var target = event.target || event.srcElement; // IE uses event.srcElement
    if(target.nodeName === 'LI') {
        target.style.fontWeight = "800";
    }
}

function MouseOut(event) {
    event = event || window.event;
    var target = event.target || event.srcElement;
    if(target.nodeName === 'LI') {
        target.style.fontWeight = "100";
    }
}


// get a reference to the UL element somehow
ulElement.onmouseover = MouseOver;
ulElement.onmouseout = MouseOut;
```

*(the node test might have to be tweaked (or even removed), this is just an example)*

As mentioned in an other answer, if you just perform style adjustments, you could solve this with pure CSS. Nevertheless, event delegation is an important concept to avoid unnecessary event handler assignment.

[Read more about event handling](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_tradmod.html).

Comment: Thanx a lot for your link above, (it is somewhat exhausting to read through the tons of webpages to find good explanation). I did not know how to catch events in the general manner.

Comment: @lyborko: Make sure you also read the other pages about events on quirksmode: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html, http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_early.html, http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html I think it is a very good explanation and also mentions all the cross browser issues. You will have a much better understanding of event handling.

Answer (score 1):

Here's classic javascript:

```
var onOver = function(e){
    e = e || window.event;
    var el = e.target || e.srcElement;
    el.style.fontWeight = 800;
}
var onOut = function(e){
    e = e || window.event;
    var el = e.target || e.srcElement;
    el.style.fontWeight = 100;
}
if (document.getElementsByClassName)
  var li = document.getElementsByClassName("signs_LI");
else{
  var li = [], lii = document.getElementsByTagName('LI');
  for (var l = 0; l < lii.length; l++){
    if (/\bsigns_LI\b/.test(lii[l].className))
      li.push(lii[l]);
  }
}
for (var e = 0; e < li.length; e++){
    var el = li[e];
    if (el.addEventListener) {
        el.addEventListener ("mouseover",onOver,false);
        el.addEventListener ("mouseout",onOut,false);
    } else if (el.attachEvent) {
        el.attachEvent ("onmouseover",onOver);
        el.attachEvent ("onmouseout",onOut);
    } else {
        el.onmouseover = onOver;
        el.onmouseout = onOut;
    }
}
```

But begs the question why you don't use standard css' `:hover` pseudo-class (javascript appears too heavy for this kind of manipulation).

Comment: Just a couple problems. Your handler functions are using `this` to reference the element, but `attachEvent` doesn't make `this` reference the element. It'll be `window` instead. You'd need to wrap it in a function that calls the `onOver/Out` functions with the proper context. Also, IE doesn't support `getElementsByClassName` (well IE9 does). :o)

Comment: @patrickdw: Hrm, tested in on my side and it worked. Just went with it. ;p This is why I tend to stick with jQuery "Focus on the code". ;p

Comment: But you tested in Firefox or Chrome or something, right? Those should work fine. Just IE would need to be tweaked.

Comment: @Brad Christie : do you mean, jquery is "platform proof"?

Comment: @patrickdw: See if [that update works](http://www.jsfiddle.net/aznq9/). Does here--I promise.

Comment: @patrick: Thanks for the constructive criticism. Dually noted that I stick with jQuery now though (unless it's something stupid--def. not event-driven, however). ;x

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to change the style of an element you should use CSS as @Bart said.

But for the record, you can use one event handler on a root element like so:

```
var ul = document.getElementById("signs_UL"); // or select by other means.
ul.onmouseover = function (e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  var elem = e.target || e.srcElement;

  // ...
};

ul.onmouseout = function (e) {
  // ...
};
```

Comment: I was just in the process of adding this answer. +1

Answer (score 0):

While CSS might be what you want in your example, JavaScript/jQuery will allow you to do more, which you might want.  This includes calling other functions and performing calculations.

```
function on(elem) { elem.style.color="#0cf"; }
function off(elem){ elem.style.color="#000"; }

// calling mouseover/out
$('.signs_LI').mouseover( function(){ on(this); })
              .mouseout( function(){ off(this); });


// hover example
$('.signs_LI').hover( function(){ on(this);  }
                    , function(){ off(this); } );
```

Comment: this is just an example.  i appreciate negative votes to say why they are negative

Comment: This would not work, you would have to pass `this` to `MouseOver`, not `$(this)`.

Comment: fixed, i think that's what I had originally, but I changed it.  I tested the above.

Comment: It would be easier to define the functions as `function on() {this.style....}` and just pass this function as event handler: `$(..).mouseover(on).mouseout(off)`... saves some function objects. Of course if you want to keep `on` and `off` as general purpose functions, than it is better to pass the element...

Comment: @Felix: yes, but for scalability, I don't like doing that.  In my opinion it'd be better to attach `this` to an object and pass the object to the function, but this is a proof of concept